# How to only get a slice of the results of a LDAP query?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

Given a LDAP query, is there a generic way to get a slice of the query results? For instance if I just want the items 5000 to 5999 of the query and I am just not interested in reading the first 4999 ones.

I suppose this could be achieved by incrementing numeric attributes like [inetOrgPerson employeeNumber](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#section-2.4) but I am looking for a generic solution.

I expect that this is not possible, but I could not see a clear answer to that question anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OpenLDAP at least, there is the combination of [RFC2891 Server Side Sorting of Search Results (SSS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891) and the [Scrolling View Browsing of Search Results (VLV) draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ldapext-c-api-vlv-01), often referred to as [SSSVLV](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapo-sssvlv.5.html).

The overlay can be loaded and configured with:

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
cn: module
objectClass: olcModuleList
olcModuleLoad: sssvlv

dn: olcOverlay=sssvlv,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcSssVlvConfig
olcOverlay: sssvlv
olcSssVlvMax: 1
olcSssVlvMaxKeys: 5
olcSssVlvMaxPerConn: 5
```

On the client side, this is supported a least by:

- [python-ldap](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/main/Lib/ldap/controls/vlv.py)